# SQL checking if two tables have same data for a specific ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have a table  called Catalog like so:

```
Course Number  CourseName   CourseDsc   PreReq
   1028          CS146      Data S...   1005
   1028          CS146      Data S...   2000
   1028          CS146      Data S...   2003
```

and another table called PreviousCourses like so:

```
Username     PrevCoursesID      Grade
admin          1005              A
admin          2000              A
```

Now this user admin doesn't meet the pre-requisites for the course CS146 because he has two of the three pre requisites(1005 and 2000) but is missing the pre-requisite 2003. The way my query is set up is that its checking if PreviousCourses is a subset of Catalog. Basically if any of the pre-requisites are met for a certain courses, the user is allowed to enroll in that class. I want my query to behave that the user CAN ONLY enroll if ALL the prerequisites from the catalog for a certain course are met.
My Query Attempt:

```
"Select PrevCoursesID, Grade from PreviousCourses where "
                        + "Grade <= 'D' AND "
                        + "PrevCoursesID IN (Select PreReq from Catalog where CourseNumber = '" + courseID + "') AND"
                        + " Username = '" + currentUser + "'";
```

**update: Just tried this query and this doesn't seem to work either**

```
         SELECT CATALOG.prereq, previouscourses.grade
         FROM CATALOG LEFT JOIN PREVIOUSCOURSES ON   
         CATALOG.prereq=PREVIOUSCOURSES.PREVCOURSESID AND   
    PREVIOUSCOURSES.GRADE<='D' WHERE PREVIOUSCOURSES.USERNAME='ADMIN' 
AND CATALOG.COURSENUMBER='1028'
```

Comment: is there no coursenumber in previouscourses table? how are the 2 tables connected? will all the courses have the same prerequisites?

Comment: Study SQL Injection, you code is scary!

Comment: Yea I am a little familiar with it. But unfortunately I haven't had much time on my hand to get a deeper look at it. It is just me carrying my whole team for the project which is due tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query, then roll through the resulting recordset to check if any of the `PreviousCourses.Grade` values are `NULL`.  If any are, the prereqs are not fully met.

Note that the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` combined with the absence of any sort of `WHERE` clause is guaranteeing that you'll get a row for every prereq, and by including the passing grade and user criteria in that `JOIN` criteria, you save yourself from having your check need to identify passing (thus only checking for `NULL`).

```
SELECT
    Catalog.PreReq,
    PreviousCourses.Grade
FROM
    Catalog
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PreviousCourses ON 
         Catalog.PreReq = PreviousCourses.PrevCoursesID 
         AND 
         PreviousCourses.Grade <='D' 
         AND        
         PreviousCourses.Username = 'admin'
```

Also, this is SQL Server syntax.  You didn't tag the question with your actual db server, just sql.  So if you're using mysql or sqlite or some other variant, this approach will still work, but the syntax may require tweaking.

Comment: I am sorry. This is for SQL. I am not familiar with SQL Server. I do not understand what Declare and set@username is doing.

Comment: It's just a variable.  I'll edit it out and just hardcode the value.

Comment: Where exactly is this taking in courseID variable that I have in my original query. Like how will I see if the selected course that user is trying to enroll in has all the necessary pre-reqs

Comment: I am trying this in phpMyAdmin() but it is not returning the third course with the grade null. It is not returning the third pre-req at all

Comment: @StephCurry3093 Sorry, brain fart - the query was wrong.  The user criteria needs to be part of the join, not in the `WHERE` clause or the rows with `NULL` grades will be omitted.  I've edited accordingly, please try again.

Comment: but again where is this query checking for a specific course, say CourseNumber='1028' from catalog. Also it is printing a bunch of 0s with null too

Comment: NVM got it to work. It is missing where courseNumber='1028'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are the classes a user can take:

```
DECLARE @UserName varchar(255) = 'admin'


    SELECT c.[Course Number]
    FROM Catalog c
    GROUP BY c.[Course Number]
    HAVING COUNT(1) =  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pc.PreReq) 
                        FROM PreviousCourses pc
                        WHERE pc.Username = @UserName 
                              AND c.PreReq = pc.PrevCoursesID 
                              AND pc.Grade IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'P', 'Pass')
           OR MAX(ISNULL(c.PreReq, 0)) = 0
    ORDER BY c.[Course Number]
```

(This is SQL Server)